# How to change the Caption of the Command on the toolbar from a Macro in VS2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, macros, vs-extensibility

From a macro I am accessing a command that is on the toolbar:

```
Dim name As String = "Macros.MyMacros.MyMacros.ToggleExceptions"
Dim cmd As EnvDTE.Command = DTE.Commands.Item(name)
```

How do I now change the caption of the command on the toolbar?  It does not seem to have the necessary properties.  Do I need to cast it to something else?

Comment: That macro doesn't actually accesses a command on the toolbar.  DTE.CommandBars would be a starting point, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented it:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Const BAR_NAME As String = "MenuBar"
    Const CTL_NAME = "Foo"

    ChangeCommandCaption(BAR_NAME, CTL_NAME, "Bar")
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeCommandCaption(ByVal cmdBarName As String, ByVal ctlName As String, ByVal caption As String)
    Dim bars As Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars

    bars = DirectCast(DTE.CommandBars, Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)
    If bars Is DBNull.Value Then Exit Sub

    Dim menuBar As CommandBar = bars.Item(cmdBarName)
    If menuBar Is DBNull.Value Then Exit Sub

    Dim cmdBarCtl As CommandBarControl

    Try
        cmdBarCtl = menuBar.Controls.Item(ctlName)
        If cmdBarCtl Is DBNull.Value Then Exit Sub
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    cmdBarCtl.Caption = caption
End Sub
```