# Quick way to toggle 'break on all exceptions' in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I regularly find it very useful when debugging to switch on the **Common Language Runtime Exceptions: *Thrown*** option in Visual Studio's Debug > Exceptions screen. I'd like a quick way of doing this, since it's always the same checkbox I'm toggling and that screen is very slow to load. In previous versions, it was possible to do this with a [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut), but macros have sadly been [removed from VS2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11). Does anyone know of a quick/easy way to do this with a plugin/extension/keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Exception Breaker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de) is a Visual Studio (2010, 2012, 2013) plugin created by [a fellow SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39068) for that purpose. It was created after he worried about this issue in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15582736/468244).

It currently works via a toolbar command button as well as a shortcut.

There is a [github repository](https://github.com/ashmind/ExceptionBreaker) for this project as well.